# JSF rendering popup frow a manegbean condition?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, popup, richfaces

I´m using this for show a message in login when a error happens:

```
<a4j:region rendered="#{usuario.fail == 1}">
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"
                style="width: 470px; margin: 10px auto;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                Invalid user or password.
            </div>
        </a4j:region>
```

But, I want to show a popup, however, this is not working, i'm trying somethings like this:

```
<h:outputScript rendered="#{usuario.fail == 1}">
            #{rich:component('popup')}.show();
        </h:outputScript>

        <rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="false" autosized="true" resizeable="false">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Simple popup panel" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="controls">
                    <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide(); return false;">
                        X
                    </h:outputLink>
                </f:facet>
                <p>Any content might be inside this panel.</p>

                <p>
                    The popup panel is open and closed from the javascript function of component client side object. The following code
                    <a href="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide()">hide this panel</a>:
                    <f:verbatim>&#35;</f:verbatim>{rich:component('popup')}.hide()
                </p>
            </rich:popupPanel>
```

I'm trying this example:

[Simple popup example](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&sample=simplePopup&skin=blueSky)

Are there a way to show a popup from a manegedbean's return ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please elaborate "not working correctly" in developer's terms instead of enduser's terms. The script `RichFaces.component('popup').show()` is being rendered? And it is being executed? And what happens thereafter ...? Any JS error? Or?

Comment: This error happens TypeError: RichFaces.$(...) is undefined
 

RichFaces.$('popup').show(), and this popup is not rendered

Comment: Much better. Well, the cause (and therefore also the answer) is now obvious there. That JS variable is undefined. Apparently the RichFaces script is not (auto)included, or you're using a RichFaces version not supporting this construct. To exclude the first, is the RichFaces script properly included in the head?

Comment: Is there other way to use it in richfaces 4 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling the function before the popupPanel is created, that's why you're getting the undefined error.

You don't have to render a JS function in order to show the panel though, you can just show the panel:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="popup" show="#{usuario.fail == 1}" …>
    …
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that's exactly what was happening !